# How Memory Allocation Is Assign To Each Attribute In Database

Tags: sql-server

I am wondering about the memory allocation in database whether it assign the memory on the base of `DataType` of the column or it assign according to the value. Being a .net developer i have the concept that memory allocation is assign on the bases of `DataType` not on the value. Now I have question how memory allocation is handled on DB side.

FOR EXAMPLE

### |  id1    |  id2   | id3    | name

|  `NULL` | `NULL` | `NULL` | James Bond

id1,id2,id3 has null values, what will be the memory size of this row. will it assign the memory to the columns having null values?

**Edit**

Database Server SQLServer2008 r2

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-storage-internals-101/

Comment: I read the article it is very informative but my question is unclear. I had a point which is pointed in the article "  As fixed-length data columns always take up their allotted space, we need the null bitmap to know whether a value is null" when the nullis assigned to a fixed column size it allocate it memory can i check the memory of each inserted row in a table from a sql command??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the answer on MSDN

**Use Sparse Columns**

The SQL Server Database Engine uses the SPARSE keyword in a column definition to optimize the storage of values in that column. Therefore, when the column value is NULL for any row in the table, the values require no storage.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Physical storage for SQL Server is in a unit called a "page". There are several structures within a page, those structures are called "records". There are several types of records, the type of record you seem to be asking about is called a "data record".

(There are also several other types of records within a page: index records, forwarding records, ghost records, text records, and other internal record structures (allocation bitmaps, file headers, etc.)

To answer your question, without delving into all those details, and neglecting a discussion of "row compression" and "page compression"...

One part of the record is for the "fixed length" columns, where the columns that are defined with fixed length datatypes are stored (integer, float, date, char(n), etc.). As the name implies, a fixed amount of storage is reserved for each column. Another part of the record is the "variable length" portion, where columns with datatypes of variable length are stored, arranged as an array, a two-byte count of the number of variable length columns, and for each column, a two-byte offset to the end of the column value.

**Q: what will be the memory size of this row.**

**A:** In your case, the table with four columns, there will be eight bytes for the record header, some fixed number of bytes for the fixed length columns, three bytes for the NULL bitmap, and a variable amount of storage for the variable length columns.

The "memory size for the row" is really determined by the datatypes of the columns, and for variable length columns, the values that are stored.

(And if any indexes exist, there's also space required in index records.)

**Q:** will it assign the memory to the columns having null values?

If the columns are fixed length, yes. If columns are variable length, yes, at a minimum, the two byte offset to the end of the value, even if the value is zero length.

SQL Server manages memory in "pages"... In terms of estimating memory requirements, the more pertinent question is "how many rows fit in a page", and "how many pages are required to store my rows?"

A page that contains one data record requires 4KB of memory. A page that contains a dozen data records requires 4KB of memory.

Comment: Spencer thanks for your time. Each Record Page has 8kb regardless of the data in it. if id1 have null value and id2 have value if it assign the memory to id1 which is in actual have no data. Can i check from the command for each inserted row in table how much memory it gets ?