# Table size in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL i know how to get the size of the database using
`EXEC sp_spaceused`
I have a question how can i get the size of a table in Sql Server database.

like Employee Table in the database.

**Thanks In advance.**

Comment: question, why do you need the table size?

Comment: Tanner i need the answer for my question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112601/how-memory-allocation-is-assign-to-each-attribute-in-database

Comment: that doesn't really answer my question as to why you want/need this information.

Answer (score 1):

This slightly involved T-SQL statement will give you the exact same information that `sp_spaceused` returns:

```
WITH pages AS 
(
    SELECT
        object_id,
        SUM(reserved_page_count) AS reserved_pages,
        SUM(used_page_count) AS used_pages,
        SUM(CASE 
               WHEN (index_id < 2)
                  THEN (in_row_data_page_count + lob_used_page_count + row_overflow_used_page_count)
               ELSE lob_used_page_count + row_overflow_used_page_count
            END) AS pages
    FROM
        sys.dm_db_partition_stats
    GROUP BY
        object_id),
extra AS 
(
    SELECT
        p.object_id,
        SUM(reserved_page_count) AS reserved_pages,
        SUM(used_page_count) AS used_pages
    FROM
        sys.dm_db_partition_stats p
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.internal_tables it ON p.object_id = it.object_id
    WHERE
        it.internal_type IN (202, 204, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216)
    GROUP BY
        p.object_id)
SELECT
    SchemaName = s.NAME,
    TableName = t.NAME,
    CompleteName = s.NAME + '.' + t.NAME,
    (p.reserved_pages + ISNULL(e.reserved_pages, 0)) * 8 AS reserved_kb,
    pages * 8 AS data_kb ,
    (CASE 
        WHEN p.used_pages + ISNULL(e.used_pages, 0) > pages
          THEN (p.used_pages + ISNULL(e.used_pages, 0) - pages)
          ELSE 0
     END) * 8 AS index_kb ,
    (CASE 
        WHEN p.reserved_pages + ISNULL(e.reserved_pages, 0) > p.used_pages + ISNULL(e.used_pages, 0)
          THEN (p.reserved_pages + ISNULL(e.reserved_pages, 0) - p.used_pages + ISNULL(e.used_pages, 0))
          ELSE 0
     END) * 8 AS unused_kb
FROM
    pages p
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables t ON t.object_id = p.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    extra e ON p.object_id = e.object_id
WHERE
    t.is_ms_shipped = 0
ORDER BY
    s.Name, t.Name
```

Of course, ideally, you'd "hide" this in a nicely useable stored procedure of your own to make it available whenever you need it ...

Answer (score 0):

in mysql You can use this query to show the size of a table:

```
SELECT table_name AS "Table", 
round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) "Size in MB" 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE table_schema = "$DB_NAME"
AND table_name = "$TABLE_NAME";
```

in sql:

sp_spaceused can get you information on the disk space used by a table, indexed view, or the whole database.

```
USE MyDatabase; GO

EXEC sp_spaceused N'dbo.MyTable'; GO
```

use this for all tables at once:

```
USE MyDatabase; GO 

sp_msforeachtable 'EXEC sp_spaceused [?]' GO
```

Comment: Actually i am stuck in a situation i have a table t which have w int column1,column2 can be null value. If i insert the value in column1 and column2 is null then how many byte will it get at the row level .

Comment: SQL NULL value reserves one or two bytes in the record directory. Besides that, an SQL NULL value reserves zero bytes in the data part of the record if stored in a variable length column. In a fixed-length column, it reserves the fixed length of the column in the data part of the record.

Comment: Column having null will occupy space ? 4 byte for int ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112601/how-memory-allocation-is-assign-to-each-attribute-in-database

Answer (score 0):

One way is to look at the `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` output.

The min_record_size_in_bytes, max_record_size_in_bytes and avg_record_size_in_bytes will give you the sizes you want.

If you want to see the size of a particular record, another way is to find the physical row location, see

[SQL Server 2008: New (undocumented) physical row locator function.](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/sql-server-2008-new-undocumented-physical-row-locator-function/)

You can then dump the row physical structure, see Anatomy of a Record.